# How to do avoid IO on every insert in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I am trying to speed up Postgresq inserts.
I saw lots of articles playing with fsync, synchronous_commit, etc.
I set parameters to get fastest writes and I still hear from HDD every insert and DB server definitely does IO just like buffer is always full. What did I miss?

```
create unlogged table ...;
--  just one insert takes about 400 ms
```

postgresq config

```
wal_level = minimal                                                        
fsync = off        
synchronous_commit = off                
full_page_writes = off              
wal_compression = off                 
wal_buffers = 128MB                  
wal_writer_delay = 1000ms    
wal_writer_flush_after = 4MB
```

Comment: What else is on that table? Indexes? Triggers? Could you show us the schema?

Comment: What is your goal here, to make the inserts faster or to make your HDD quieter or what?

Answer (score 5):

Not every `INSERT` causes I/O, every commit does. Other than that, checkpoints do most of the I/O (if `shared_buffers` is big enough).

These are the tips to speed up loading:

- increase `max_wal_size` to reduce unnecessary checkpoints
- see that `shared_buffers` is not too small
- use many `INSERT`s in a single transaction
- use prepared statements to be faster
- use `COPY` to be fastest
- `COPY (FREEZE)` into a table (or partition - hint) that was created or truncated in the same transaction to be fastester

Keep your fingers from `fsync`, it has to stay `on`.